# Installing TexLive with custom-maked binaries

Tags: installing, texlive

I'm going to install TexLive2014 with my own-compiled binaries (with shared libs).

## 0. I have read this:

```
https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlbuild.html
https://www.tug.org/texlive/build.html
https://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/pst/texlive.html
```

## 1. Build binaries:

In sources dir:

```
> $ mkdir Work && cd Work $ ../configure \
> --prefix=/opt/texlive/2014 \
> --bindir=/opt/texlive/2014/bin/custom \
> --datarootdir=/opt/texlive/2014 \
> --includedir=/usr/include \
> --infodir=/opt/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/doc/info \
> --libdir=/usr/lib \
> --mandir=/opt/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/doc/man \
> --disable-native-texlive-build \
> --disable-static \
> --enable-shared \
> --with-system-libgs \
> --with-system-poppler \
> --with-system-freetype2 \
> --with-system-fontconfig \
> --with-system-libpng \
> --with-system-icu \
> --with-system-graphite2 \
> --with-system-harfbuzz \
> --with-system-xpdf \
> --with-system-cairo \
> --with-system-pixman \
> --with-system-zlib \
> --with-banner-add=" - shared" 
> $ make 
> $ make check 
> $ make install
```

At the end of this I was taking binaries in /opt/texlive/2014/bin/custom 
and some files around there (in texmf-dist).

## 2. Install TexLive dist (tree):

In untarred dist dir:

```
$ ./install-tl -custom-bin /opt/texlive/2014/bin/custom/
```

(As I understand that will install full tree of TexLive using my pre-installed 
binaries for 'custom' platform.)

Than add '/opt/texlive/2014/bin/custom' to my $PATH and '/opt/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/doc/info' to $INFOPATH, '/opt/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/doc/man'  to $MANPATH.

```
$ fmtutil-sys --all
$ updmap-sys
```

## ?. Questions:

- Is key '-custom-bin' tells to installer that  it should using bins in this directory directly 
  or should copying them?
- There are no some additional executables (maybe scripts? or/and symlinks?) in bin directory,
  so some commands (such as 'latex', 'pdflatex') not found. Where it is and how to install it?
- Installer script installed another copy of manpages to bin/custom/man directory. 
  Is it differs of manpages that comes with own-making binaries? 
  How to prevent of install these mans correctly (*perfectionism style*)?
- Any comments to my sequence?

Comment: I have the same question. What is the minimal set of `--custom-bin` files to have `install-tl` make a working pdflatex system (including fmt files)? I symlinked kpsewhich and pdftex into my `custom_bin` directory. But I can't make it run `updmap-sys` and `fmtutil-sys`... I've tried symlinking `fmtutil.pl` and `fmtutil-sys.sh` in `custom_bin`, but it didn't help.