# Minimal contents of --custom-bin directory for install-tl to install with custom binary of pdftex

Tags: texlive, installing

What is minimal contents of `--custom-bin` directory to use with `install-tl` with custom `pdftex` to get a working TDS? (I guess including the run of `updmap-sys` and `fmtutil-sys`)

I'm trying with:

- `pdftex`
- `kpsewhich`
- `kpseaccess`
- `kpsestat`
- `mktexlsr` (symlink)
- `fmtutil.pl` (symlink)
- `updmap.pl` (symlink)
- `fmtutil-sys.sh` (wrapper to add `--sys` to argv and calling `fmtutil.pl`)
- `updmap-sys.sh` (wrapper to add `--sys` to argv and calling `updmap.pl`)

Is anything else needed?

My current error:

```
...
Installing [106/109, time/total: 00:13/00:13]: uniquecounter [292k]
Installing [107/109, time/total: 00:13/00:13]: url [266k]
Installing [108/109, time/total: 00:13/00:13]: xdvi [175k]
Installing [109/109, time/total: 00:13/00:13]: zapfding [46k]
Time used for installing the packages: 00:13
running mktexlsr /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist ...
writing fmtutil.cnf to /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
writing updmap.cfg to /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/native:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/native/share/texmf-local/web2c:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/native/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/native/share/texmf/web2c:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/native/texmf-local/web2c:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/native/texmf-dist/web2c:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/native/texmf/web2c:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/share/texmf-local/web2c:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/share/texmf/web2c:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texmf-local/web2c:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texmf-dist/web2c:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texmf/web2c:/home/runner/work/busytex/texmf-local/web2c:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/share/texmf-local/web2c:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/share/texmf/web2c:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/texmf-local/web2c:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/texmf-dist/web2c:/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/texmf/web2c.
writing language.dat to /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat
writing language.def to /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.def
writing language.dat.lua to /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat.lua
running mktexlsr /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-config /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist ...
running updmap-sys --nohash ...failed
re-running mktexlsr /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-config ...
./source/texmfrepo/install-tl: updmap-sys --nohash failed (status 1): 
pre-generating all format files, be patient...
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --no-strict --all ...failed
running package-specific postactions
./source/texmfrepo/install-tl: fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --no-strict --all failed (status 1): 
Can't open perl script "/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/tlpkg/tlpostcode/dvipdfmx.pl": No such file or directory
./source/texmfrepo/install-tl: calling post action script tlpkg/tlpostcode/dvipdfmx.pl did not succeed in /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex, status 2 at source/texmfrepo/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 1793.

./source/texmfrepo/install-tl: errors in installation reported above

finished with package-specific postactions
Summary of warnings:

./source/texmfrepo/install-tl: updmap-sys --nohash failed (status 1): 

./source/texmfrepo/install-tl: fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --no-strict --all failed (status 1): 
Welcome to TeX Live!
```

The log of successful run of `install-tl` without `--custom-bin`:

```
...
Installing [127/127, time/total: 00:13/00:13]: zapfding [46k]
Time used for installing the packages: 00:13
running mktexlsr /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist ...
writing fmtutil.cnf to /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
writing updmap.cfg to /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
writing language.dat to /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat
writing language.def to /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.def
writing language.dat.lua to /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat.lua
running mktexlsr /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-config /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist ...
running updmap-sys --nohash ...done
re-running mktexlsr /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-config ...
pre-generating all format files, be patient...
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --no-strict --all ...done
running package-specific postactions

finished with package-specific postactions
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------

 The following environment variables contain the string "tex"

 (case-independent).  If you're doing anything but adding personal
Welcome to TeX Live!
 directories to the system paths, they may well cause trouble somewhere

 while running TeX.  If you encounter problems, try unsetting them.

 Please ignore spurious matches unrelated to TeX.
See /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/index.html for links to documentation.

The TeX Live web site (https://tug.org/texlive/) contains any updates and corrections. TeX Live is a joint project of the TeX user groups around the world; please consider supporting it by joining the group best for you. The list of groups is available on the web at https://tug.org/usergroups.html.
    GITHUB_REPOSITORY=busytex/busytex

    GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER=busytex

    GITHUB_WORKSPACE=/home/runner/work/busytex/busytex
Add /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/doc/man to MANPATH.
    RUNNER_WORKSPACE=/home/runner/work/busytex
    TEXLIVE_INSTALL_NO_RESUME=1
    UBUNTUPACKAGES=texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-recommended texlive-science
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Add /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/doc/info to INFOPATH.
Most importantly, add /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/bin/x86_64-linux
to your PATH for current and future sessions.
Logfile: /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/install-tl.log
```

Related question: [Installing TexLive with custom-maked binaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192650/installing-texlive-with-custom-maked-binaries)

Thanks!

Comment: you only need the first of the ones you list the others are never run automatically, fmtutil-sys is helpful to manage building multiple formats with the right options but if you just want pdftex.fmt all you need is pdftex and then `pdftex --ini pdftex.ini`  will make the fmt. But ot depends on your OS Ithink on windows the executable is just a shell calling some dll, so you need those as well.

Comment: It failed to proceed with installation until I added `kpsewhich`. Currently I'm invoking `--ini` manually, but it's rather brittle and requires a lot of env. variables: https://github.com/busytex/busytex/blob/2c0439473ac7203fec751bf0da3526cb75627804/Makefile#L436-L447

So I'd rather have `install-tl` figure this out for me

Comment: well fair enough but that's a very fluid definition of `minimal`

Comment: I've updated the question with more info and logs

Comment: I've done some tracing and I think it's failing because `kpsewhich` for some reason does not produce correct outputs when `updmap.pl` is called. Maybe related to problems with not found `texmf.cnf` which sets the needed variables. So the question becomes why does it not find the `texmf.cnf` or why does it not get generated?

Comment: What `KPATHSEA_DEBUG` should I set for it to print actually found path? `KPATHSEA_DEBUG=32` only showed searched directories, not the final path. Now trying `KPATHSEA_DEBUG=104`

Comment: For now, I can't even get the `pdftex` detected if I make `custom_bin/kpsewhich` link to extracted `bin/x86_64-linux/kpsewhich`, but it still does not detect any `pdftex` programs and generates no `*.fmt` files